# query to break a column into multiple columns using bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column that has the following value: **d4b30135-476d-43e9-a269-9c0512a77a19#ANDROID#US#Age#JohnDoe#Male**

I would like to create multiple columns using the above string
Col Names: Device, Country, Age, UserName, Gender
Col Values: Android, US, 13-21, JohnDoe,  Male

I am thinking about using REG EXTRACT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select * except(your_col) from (
  select your_col, offset, value from your_table, 
  unnest(split(your_col, '#')) value with offset
)
pivot (
  any_value(value) 
  for ['', 'Device', 'Country', 'Age', 'UserName', 'Gender'][safe_offset(offset)] 
  in ('Device', 'Country', 'Age', 'UserName', 'Gender')
)
```

if to apply for sample data as in your question - output is

[image]